# DuckDb csv data load - How to avoid appending .0 to integer values while loading data from csv into DuckDb table column having 'numeric' data type?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, duckdb

I have csv file which I want to load into DuckDb table. CSV file has two columns col1 & col2 having both integer values. I want to load this csv file data into DuckDb table - temp which have same columns as col1(dtype int) & col2(dtype numeric).

CSV file like below

```
col1,col2
10,20
11,21
```

I used COPY command to load data.

```
conn = duckdb.connect()
cur = conn.cursor()
query1 = "create schema public;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.temp(col1 integer,col2 numeric)"
query2 = "COPY public.temp FROM \'/Users/data.csv\' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true)"
cur.execute(query1)
cur.execute(query2)
conn.commit()
```

Data is loaded in DuckDb table like below

```
col1,col2
10,20.0
11,21.0
```

So data loaded correctly for int column but appended .0 for numeric column.
This doesn't happen with Postgresql db table.

Why is this happening ? Any solution for this ?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Most likely an issue in your SQL client, how to present a numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

Re: Postgres, it depends:

`select 1::numeric(4,2); 1.0`

vs

`select 1::numeric; 1`.

This is due to [Postgres Numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL):

> (The SQL standard requires a default scale of 0, i.e., coercion to integer precision. We find this a bit useless. If you're concerned about portability, always specify the precision and scale explicitly.)

In the DuckDB case [Duckdb Numeric](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/data_types/numeric):

> The default WIDTH and SCALE is DECIMAL(18, 3), if none are specified

So in DuckDB CLI:

`select 1::numeric; 1.000`

vs

`select 1::numeric(4,0); 1`

Declare your field with a `0` scale, though if you are doing that just make the field an integer.